# react native date time picker modal, only show month and year

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using `react-native-modal-datetime-picker`. I only want to display month and year and hide dates, is there any way to hide date and only display month and year in `react-native-modal-datetime-picker`. If yes, can someone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems [you can't achieve that using](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/issues/157) `react-native-modal-datetime-picker`

May be you could try [`react-native-month-selector`](https://github.com/vinodkumar8/react-native-month-selecto) or other library